# Animation Listener errors with Intent

Tags: java, android

This code is supposed to do the animation I've set when a button is clicked, wait for the animation to finish, then load a new activity.  When I tried to add the listener, I get errors for my Intent constructor.  Any help would be great.

```
public void onClick (View v)  {
       switch (v.getId()){
           case R.id.buttonStart:
               wobble.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                       buttonStart.startAnimation(wobble);
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                       startActivity(new Intent(this,CityRendActivity.class));
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                   }
               });



               break;
       }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `this` that you're passing in `onAnimationEnd` is the `AnimationListener` that is being created. You'll need to specify the `this` that you're passing to the `Intent` constructor is your activity:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, CityRendActivity.class));
}
```